# Possible dimensions of $V \cap W$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, intersection-theory, gre-exam, invariant-subspace

If $V$ and $W$ are two dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, what are the possible dimensions of $V \cap W$ if;

- $V$ and $W$ have the same dimensions? (for example; $\dim(V)=2, \dim(W)=2, n=3$)
- $V$ and $W$ have different dimensions? (for example; $\dim(V)=4, \dim(W)=5, n=10$)

I am having difficulties to solve this kind of problems. (NOTE: I am not asking you to solve the following two problems, but I am asking about the formulea to be used, then I will try solving them).

[image]

[image]

I have already saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879023/finding-the-possible-dimensions-of-the-intersection-of-subspaces), but could not find a general formula.

Comment: This is a problem where understanding is going to be much more fruitful than just learning a formula.

Comment: @GregMartin Could you please provide some good links and/or books to refer to that? I did not study such things, so the references will hopefully be readable. I need something written for non-math major. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $U\cap V \subset U$ and $U\cap V \subset V$, we have
$$\color{blue}{\dim (U\cap V) \le \min \{\dim(U), \dim(V)\}}$$
In case you didn't know, we also have
$${\dim(U\cap V) = \dim(U) + \dim(V) - \dim(U+V)}$$
Note that $${n \ge \dim(U+V) \ge \max\{\dim U, \dim V\}}$$ since $V \subset U+V$ and $U \subset U+V$. Combining this with the previous equality, we have
$$\color{blue}{\dim(U) + \dim(V) - n \le \dim(U\cap V) \le \dim(U) + \dim(V) - \max\{\dim(U), \dim(V)\}}$$

You should be able to tackle your questions now.

Comment: Based on your answer, QUESTION(19) in the OP: $2+2-4 \le \dim(U \cap W) \le 2+2-2$ or $0 \le \dim(U \cap W) \le 2$ and the answer is D. QUESTION(29) in OP: $4+4-7 \le \dim(U \cap W) \le 4+4-4$ or $1 \le \dim(U \cap W) \le 4$ so the intersection cannot be $0$ and the answer is A. If I am right, then you are awesome.

Comment: I think you're right, and hence I'm awesome! Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if it helped you :)